# There is always a default background on TextInputLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginUsernameText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_input_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_input_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_input_margin_top_bottom"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginButtonLogin">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginPasswordText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_input_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_input_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_input_margin_top_bottom"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_below="@id/loginUsernameText">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is my styles.xml file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

So I am not using anything extra on TextInputLayout and they are appearing like this
[image]

This grey background is always there.
How do I remove this background and just get the default TextInputLayout. Thanks.

Comment: check this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/102

Answer (score 77, accepted):

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/102

It seems a material textfield bug.
You can use this code to change background white temporarily.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent" 
   android:background="@android:color/transparent">
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 40):

One way to remove the background color is to adjust the background mode of TextInputLayout.

app:boxBackgroundMode="none"

Worked for me.

Example XML Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/comment_placeholder"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="500" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Enjoy all the reputation! Haha! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: After I updated material design in my project, I noticed text input layouts with boxBackgroundMode set to none displayed an error icon. Not sure if this is a bug, but I set the error icon color to transparent to resolve it for now. - "app:errorIconTint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: It removes underline too

Comment: My `TextInputLayout` wraps an `AutoCompleteTextView` to implement a material spinner. I also had to set `app:endIconMode="none"` because the default material style applies a drop down arrow to the TIL as an end icon.  If not set, an exception is thrown: `The current box background mode 0 is not supported by the end icon mode 3`. But once I do this, the drop down no longer works!

Comment: Doesn't look as expected. Underline is missing. Solution of Mina chen seems to work.

Answer (score 15):

**Method A**

*(completely transparent background)*

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@null"
..>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
..>
```

**Method B**

*(solid background colour)*

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="?android:attr/colorBackground"
..>
```

*For my case, I needed it to be fully transparent as the screen background is not a solid colour. If that's the case for you, go with **Method A**

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked with `app:boxBackgroundColor="@null"`, like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@null"
        android:hint="@string/description">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

In me case needed change background in TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple way worked for me!

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced with this issue. None of the above solutions worked for the latest material theme release. Took me a while to figure it out. Here's my solution:

**Style:**

```
<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        style="@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/agreement"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Also I strongly recommend you to check this article out. [Migrating to
> Material Components for Android](http://Migrating%20to%20Material%20Components%20for%20Android)

Answer (score 3):

The default background color is based on the **`colorOnSurface`** attribute.

You can override this value using:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout_overlay"
   ..>
```

with:

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayout_overlay">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

or you can use the **`boxBackgroundColor`** attribute (in the layout or in a custom style):

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/....."
      ..>
```

Comment: <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/....."
      ..> worked to me. Thanks

Comment: With this trick, there is a tiny ugly appearance of hint text.

Answer (score 0):

At beginning everything was working fine. Later layout was broken. The reason was I changed property background TextInputEditText. Transaparency must be set on TextInputEditText, not in TextInputLayout **`android:background="#80FFFFFF"`**

Comment: I don't believe that a problem with the background (color) could break the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these options to customise the TextInputLayout.

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menuMakeList"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_round_menu_selector"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHeader">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="null"
                        android:hint="Make"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        app:hintTextColor="#C8CCC9" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is how it will be coming up. I have used my custom rounded corners xml as background and override the colors from material **background_round_menu_selector.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#EAEAEA" />
</shape>
```

[image]